# Padding a files with n number of spaces at the end of the line

Tags: shell, unix, sh, padding, aix

I have a file which looks like below format. I want to padd it with spaces at the end of line.

File1.txt

```
Steve Smith
Thomas Muller
Tim Cook
Bill Gates
```

I have used below command but it is not giving me the desired output,it is spliting as

```
Steve 
Smith
```

and then giving output.

```
while read line; do printf "%-20s\n" $line; done < file1.txt
```

The desired output for the above files is as below.s is the spaces added for padding the each line.

```
Steve Smithssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
Thomas Mullerssssssssssssssssssssssssss
Tim Cooksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
Bill Gatessssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable `line` and better to use `read -r`:

```
while read -r line; do printf "%-20s\n" "$line"; done < file1.txt
```

Test:

```
while read -r line; do printf "%-20s\n" "$line"; done < file1.txt | cat -vte
Steve Smith         $
Thomas Muller       $
Tim Cook            $
Bill Gates          $
```

Comment: `help read` says: `-r do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`. For your case it might not be required but always good to have.